# snakemake : rule's input with different pattern

Tags: python, bioinformatics, snakemake

I am new to snakemake and would like to use the following rule :

```
input_path = config["PATH"]
samples = pd.read_csv(config["METAFILE"], sep = '\t', header = 0)['sample']

rule getPaired:
        output:
            fwd = temp(tmp_path + "/reads/{sample}_fwd.fastq.gz"),
            rev = temp(tmp_path + "/reads/{sample}_rev.fastq.gz")
        params:
            input_path = input_path
        run:
            shell("scp -i {params.input_path}/{wildcards.sample}_*1*.f*q.gz {output.fwd}"),
            shell("scp -i {params.input_path}/{wildcards.sample}_*2*.f*q.gz {output.rev}")
```

Input files have different patterns :

1. **{sampleID}_R[1-2]_001.fq.gz** (for example : 2160_J15_S480_R1_001.fastq.gz)
2. **{sampleID}_[1-2].fq.gz** (for example : SRX000001_1.fq.gz)

The getPaired rule works for input like **{sample}_[1-2].fq.gz** but not for the second pattern.

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 2):

You should make use of [input functions](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/snakefiles/rules.html#input-functions-and-unpack). I made an example which isn't really what you need, but I think it should clearly show what you want to achieve:

```
paths = {'sample1': '/home/jankees/data',
         'sample2': '/mnt/data',
         'sample3': '/home/christina/fastq'}

extensions = {'sample1': '.fq.gz',
              'sample2': '.fq.gz',
              'sample3': '.fastq.gz'}

def get_input(wildcards):
    input_file = paths[wildcards.sample] + "/read/" + wildcards.sample + extensions[wildcards.sample]
    return input_file

rule all:
    input:
        ["sample1_trimmed.fastq.gz", 
         "sample2_trimmed.fastq.gz", 
         "sample3_trimmed.fastq.gz"]

rule trim:
    input:
        get_input
    output:
        "{sample}_trimmed.fastq.gz"
    shell:
        "touch {output}"
```